# Join two tables using specified fields in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have two tables called `Siteaddress` and `Jobsheet`. In the `Jobsheet` table there is a field called `siteaddress` that contains the ID of the site address stored in the `Siteaddress` table.

The problem I am having is that while I'm doing the join in the controller, CakePHP is joining the `Siteaddress` table to the `Jobsheet` table using the `id` fields in both tables. This causes a problem as there is only one record (so far) in the `Siteaddress` table, and multiple records in the `Jobsheet` table.

What I need to do is tell CakePHP to join `Jobsheet.siteaddress` to `Siteaddress.id` instead of the way it's working at the moment.

How am I able to do this?

Below is the relationship code from the `Jobsheet` model file:

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'Company' => array(
        'className' => 'Company',
        'foreignKey' => 'id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Siteaddress' => array(
        'className' => 'Siteaddress',
        'foreignKey' => 'id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the `foreignKey` to `id` so Cake uses this for making the join. This key can be set to any table field you want in the table you want joined. If I understand you correctly you should set the `foreignKey` to `siteaddress`:

```
'Siteaddress' => array(
    'className' => 'Siteaddress',
    'foreignKey' => 'siteaddress',
    'conditions' => '',
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => ''
)
```

See [the manual entry](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasone) for `hasOne` as well.

**EDIT:**

In this case `$belongsTo` might be a better fit as an association.

Comment: I have set it to `siteaddress` but it then comes back with the error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Siteaddress.siteaddress' in 'on clause'`

Comment: Ah, you're right. In that case `hasOne` might not be the association you're looking for. Defining a `$belongsTo` association with the `siteaddress` `foreignKey` might be a better option.